# Execution timeout expired issue in a stored procedure on Azure SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, timeout, azure-sql-database, database-replication

I got a problem with execution of a stored procedure on Azure SQL. By the way, the procedure is huge and average execution time is about 30–40 seconds.

There is a main database and a replica.

My API works with the replica DB and besides that, there are some synchronization services are synchronizing some data to this DB from other data sources.

The problem is the timeout that I'm getting from time to times when running the stored procedure. It happens when I'm requesting some data that's supposed to be touched by the sync services. On the other hand, if I run the SQL as a raw SQL from the API code, it works fine.

I'm confused why it's happening and have no idea how to proceed, but I have to keep the stored procedure running.

Are there any ideas how to fix the timeout issue?

**Updated:**
The issue appears only when I try to get data for the last day.
For example, yesterday the call of stored procedure stuck at dates:

```
declare
    @stratDate datetime2 = '2023-11-14 00:00',
    @endDate datetime2 = '2023-11-15 23:59:59'
exec procedure_name @stratDate, @endDate
```

But today it's working fine and the same issue with dates:

```
    @stratDate datetime2 = '2023-11-15 00:00',
    @endDate datetime2 = '2023-11-16 23:59:59'
```

If I extend today date range to 2 days, I get data w/o any issues

```
    @stratDate datetime2 = '2023-11-14 00:00',
    @endDate datetime2 = '2023-11-16 23:59:59'
```

And again, the raw SQL query w/o procedure always works at any dates.

**Updated 22-Nov-2023:**

In the end, I've fixed the issue using two queries inside a stored procedure instead of the one huge. The 1st query performs selection of column and filtration by where condition into the tmp table, and the 2nd one aggregates and sorts data using the tmp table.

But I'm not sure that I have clear understanding why it's worked, and what was an issue.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you could share with us if you used Azure SQL Geo-replication,  Azure SQL zone redundant server or you configured Azure SQL Data Sync? That can really help us to understand the scenario.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, No, I didn't configure Azure SQL Data Sync. I work with existing databases. Yes, it is a Geo replica. Main server is located on the East US, and replica is on the North Central US.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase the timeout on the connection string and make sure you implement a [retry logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling).

Please make sure both the primary and the secondary replicas have the same service tier. Execute the following query on the secondary to identify if the secondary has a high resource utilization, if that is the case then please try to scale up the service tier on the secondary.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```

Use below script to determine query waits and see what is the difference in terms of waits between both regions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #before;

 SELECT [wait_type], [waiting_tasks_count], [wait_time_ms], [max_wait_time_ms],
        [signal_wait_time_ms]
 INTO #before
 FROM sys.[dm_db_wait_stats];

 -- Execute test query here

 SELECT *
 FROM [dbo].[YourTestQuery]

  -- Finish test query

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #after;

 SELECT [wait_type], [waiting_tasks_count], [wait_time_ms], [max_wait_time_ms],
        [signal_wait_time_ms]
 INTO #after
 FROM sys.[dm_db_wait_stats];

 -- Show accumulated wait time

 SELECT [a].[wait_type], ([a].[wait_time_ms] - [b].[wait_time_ms]) AS [wait_time]
 FROM [#after] AS [a]
 INNER JOIN [#before] AS [b] ON
  [a].[wait_type] = [b].[wait_type]
 ORDER BY ([a].[wait_time_ms] - [b].[wait_time_ms]) DESC;
```

If you see on the secondary replica a prevalent wait named ASYNC_NETWORK_IO then network latency while sending results sets to other region may be the cause.

The recommendations we are giving you may look primitive but the thing is Query Store is not available on the secondary replicas of Azure Geo-replication configuration, because the secondary replicas are read-only and Query Store requires write access to the database. However, you can also use the [Query Performance Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use?view=azuresql) feature in the Azure portal to analyze the query performance of the secondary replica.